# django delete s3 image uploaded using custom field

Tags: amazon-s3, delete-file, django-1.9, django-custom-field

I am using a custom field to upload image on s3 using django 1.9. I want to delete image from s3 whenever model instance is deleted. I have tried post_delete signal with ImageField's delete() method but since I'm using custom field cannot achieve the result. Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
```

## .....

```
pre_delete.connect(delete_image, dispatch_uid="delete_image")
```

## .....

```
def delete_image(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    for field_name in instance._meta.get_fields():
        try:
            field = getattr(instance, field_name)
        except:
            field = None
        if isinstance(field, your_custom_field):
            your_app_utils.clean_images(field.get_images())
```

Comment: I'm new to django. can you please explain how can I clean images from the custom field.